# Initialize interface in Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, interface

**My Interface**

```
public interface Baseface {

    public void updatedName(String newName);
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Baseface baseface;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    baseface = (Baseface) this;
    baseface.updatedName("hello");

   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
   startActivity(i);
   }
```

}

**SecondActivity**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Baseface {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

}

@Override
public void updatedName(String newName) {
    Log.e("my new name is:",newName);
}
```

}

**I got error**

```
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException. MainActivity cannot be cast to Baseface
```

Comment: study well about the interface.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: using interfaces to communication between Activities is a wrong approach.

Answer (score 3):

`MainActivity` must implement `Baseface` for the cast to sucess.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Baseface
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this make your `MainActivity` implements `Baseface` so the `MainActivity` is can be cast to `Baseface`

like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Baseface {
    private Baseface baseface;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    baseface = (Baseface) this;
    baseface.updatedName("hello");

   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
   startActivity(i);
   }

}
```

**and if you want to pass data from one activity to other than you can pass data `intent` below code**

send data with `intent` using `putExtra()` method like this from your Main Activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("data", "hello");
startActivity(i);
```

now receive in your  `SecondActivity` like this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");
```